# Vending Machine give changes after they select the menu

Tags: python, classes

The program offers items, has the user pay for items, 'gives' the items. It seems to work more or less. I have 2 questions:

I don't know how to deduct the cash from cash it is deposited and when they select the item, it should detect the cash from the deposit and give back the rest of the changes

Is there a way to make the code simpler/better?

```
import time
import sys


class CashBox(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.credit = 0
       self.totalReceived = 0
       #self.price = 35

   def deposit(self, amount):
       self.credit = amount + self.credit
       self.totalReceived = amount + self.totalReceived
       print("Depositing {0} cents. You have {1} cents credit.".format(
           amount, self.credit))
       # print(type(self.credit))
       return self.credit

   def returnCoins(self):
       print("Returning ", self.credit/100, " dollars.")
       self.totalReceived = 0

   def haveYou(self, name, price, recipe):
       return self.credit >= price

   def deduct(self, amount):
       pass

   def totalCoins(self):
       return self.totalReceived


class CoffeeMachine(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.cashBox = CashBox()
       self.credit = CashBox.__init__
       self.selector = self.cashBox

   def oneAction(self):

       while True:
           command = input("""
           ______________________________________________________
           PRODUCT LIST: all 35 cents, except bouillon (25 cents)
           1=black, 2=white, 3=sweet, 4=sweet & white, 5=bouillon      
           Sample Commands: insert 25, select 1, cancel, quit.
           Your command: 
           """)
           words = command.lower().split()
           if 'select' in words:
               Selector.select(self, int(words[1]))
           elif 'insert' in words:
               coinsAllowed = [5, 10, 25, 50]
               if int(words[1]) in coinsAllowed:
                   self.cashBox.deposit(int(words[1]))
               else:
                   print(
                       """We only take half-dollars, quarters, dimes, and nickels.""")
           elif 'cancel' in words:
               print("Cancelling transaction. Returning to main menu: ")
               self.cashBox.returnCoins()
           elif 'quit' in words:
               break
           else:
               print("Invalid command.")

   def totalCash(self):
       return self.cashBox.totalReceived


class Product(object):

   def __init__(self, name, price, recipe):
       self.name = name
       self.price = price
       self.recipe = recipe

   def getPrice(self):
       return self.price

   def make(self):
       for item in self.recipe:
           print("dispensing", item)
           time.sleep(0.5)
       print("Enjoy your", self.name)
       time.sleep(0.5)
       # print(self.price)


class Selector(object):

   def __init__(self):
       #self.Product = Product()
       self.cashBox = CashBox()
       self.credit = CashBox.deposit
       # self.products.append(Product.

   def select(self, choiceIndex):
       recipes = {
           1: ["Black coffee", 35, ["cup", "coffee", "water"]],
           2: ["White coffee", 35, ["cup", "coffee", "creamer", "water"]],
           3: ["Sweet coffee", 35, ["cup", "coffee", "sugar", "water"]],
           4: ["White & Sweet coffee", 35, ["cup", "coffee", "sugar", "creamer", "water"]],
           5: ["Bouillon", 25, ["cup bouillonPowder", "water"]]
       }
       if choiceIndex in range(1, len(recipes)+1):
           self.choiceIndex = choiceIndex
           self.recipe = recipes.get(choiceIndex)
           product = Product(*self.recipe)
           if self.cashBox.haveYou(*self.recipe) == True:
               #print(self.recipe,"Great selection")
               #price = CashBox.haveYou(*self.recipe)
               product.make()
               self.cashBox.haveYou = self.cashBox.haveYou - self.cashBox.deduct
               print("Returning {0} cents.".format(self.cashBox.haveYou))
           else:
               print("Sorry. Not enough money deposited.")
       else:
           print("That selection does not exist")


def main():
   m = CoffeeMachine()
   while m.oneAction():
       pass
   total = m.totalCash()
   print(f"Total cash received: ${total/100:.2f}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The first "question" (i.e. "_I don't know how to deduct the cash from cash it is deposited and when they select the item, it should detect the cash from the deposit and give back the rest of the changes_") sounds like a feature request, which is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site - please remove it.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do with `self.credit = CashBox.__init__`. Maybe you means `self.credit = self.cashBox.creadit` but I would use `self.cashBox.creadit` instead of `self.creadit`

Comment: line `self.selector = self.cashBox` also seems useless. And `Selector.select(self,... )` is strange. It should be instance `self.sel = Selector()` (created in `__init__` ) and in `oneAction` should be `self.sel.select(int(words[1]))`

Comment: as for me machine at start should allow only `select` and when you select then you can `insert` and it should automatically compare `credit` with `price` - and when `credit >= price` then it should give coffie and give back money `credit - price`

Answer (score 1):

Don't `sleep` - it isn't helping the user experience.

Don't inherit from `object` since that's a Python 2-ism.

I don't think you treat `credit` and `totalReceived` differently enough to justify the latter; it should just go away.

Consider replacing your format calls with f-strings.

`haveYou` is a slightly confusing name - maybe call it `has_credit_for` ?

Your method names - `haveYou`, etc. - should be lower_snake_case, as in `have_you`.

`deduct` was the start to a reasonable method but was never implemented?

`totalCoins` and similar thin getter methods can just be deleted. Generally, public member variables absent getters are more Pythonic.

Assigning `__init__` to a variable makes no sense. Don't do this.

The `coinsAllowed` list should be a set `{}` due to the way that it's used.

`Product` can be instantiated during the construction of your `recipes` variable, which should be stored as a class static.

`choiceIndex` should not be stored on the class. Likewise for `recipe`.

You have a reasonable `returnCoins` method - why not call it instead of writing

```
print("Returning {0} cents.".format(self.cashBox.haveYou))
```

Passing the self *of a different object* to a non-bound `Selector.select` method is like replacing your headlights with angry eels. It's creative, but utterly terrible. Do not do this.

`oneAction` is an outright lie, since it loops until the user quits. Remove your loop in that function, and keep your loop at the outer level.

Don't `recipes.get` - use `[]`, since you never want to allow a default `None`.

There are other problems, but this is a start:

### Suggested

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class CashBox:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.credit = 0

    def deposit(self, amount: int) -> None:
        self.credit += amount
        print(f"Depositing {amount} cents. You have {self.credit} cents credit.")

    def return_coins(self) -> None:
        print(f"Returning {self.credit / 100} dollars.")
        self.credit = 0

    def has_credit_for(self, price: int) -> bool:
        return self.credit >= price

    def deduct(self, amount: int) -> None:
        self.credit -= amount


class Product(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    price: int
    recipe: list[str]

    def make(self):
        for item in self.recipe:
            print("dispensing", item)
        print("Enjoy your", self.name)


class CoffeeMachine:
    RECIPES = [
        Product(*args)
        for i, args in enumerate(
            (
                ("Black coffee", 35, ("cup", "coffee", "water")),
                ("White coffee", 35, ("cup", "coffee", "creamer", "water")),
                ("Sweet coffee", 35, ("cup", "coffee", "sugar", "water")),
                ("White & Sweet coffee", 35, ("cup", "coffee", "sugar", "creamer", "water")),
                ("Bouillon", 25, ("cup bouillonPowder", "water")),
            ), 1
        )
    ]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cash_box = CashBox()

    def one_action(self) -> bool:
        command = input("""
______________________________________________________
PRODUCT LIST: all 35 cents, except bouillon (25 cents)
1=black, 2=white, 3=sweet, 4=sweet & white, 5=bouillon      
Sample Commands: insert 25, select 1, cancel, quit.
Your command: 
""")
        words = command.lower().split()

        if 'select' in words:
            self.select(int(words[1]))
        elif 'insert' in words:
            amount = int(words[1])
            coins_allowed = {5, 10, 25, 50}
            if amount in coins_allowed:
                self.cash_box.deposit(amount)
            else:
                print("We only take half-dollars, quarters, dimes, and nickels.")
        elif 'cancel' in words:
            print("Cancelling transaction. Returning to main menu: ")
            self.cash_box.return_coins()
        elif 'quit' in words:
            return False
        else:
            print("Invalid command.")

        return True

    def select(self, choice_index: int) -> None:
        if choice_index not in range(1, len(self.RECIPES) + 1):
            print("That selection does not exist")
            return

        product = self.RECIPES[choice_index - 1]
        if self.cash_box.has_credit_for(product.price):
            product.make()
            self.cash_box.deduct(product.price)
            self.cash_box.return_coins()
        else:
            print("Sorry. Not enough money deposited.")


def main() -> None:
    m = CoffeeMachine()
    while m.one_action():
        pass
    print(f"Total credit: ${m.cash_box.credit / 100:.2f}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```